# Solving the Legendre orthogonality condition for m = n

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

The integral I'm trying to evaluate is 
$I = \frac{(-1)^m2m!}{2^{2m}(m!)^{2}} \int_{-1}^{1} (x^{2} - 1)^m dx$
to get the orthogonality condition 
$I = \int_{-1}^{1} P_m(x) P_n(x) dx = \frac{2}{2n + 1} \delta_{n,m}$

I've tried splitting the integrand into $(x +1)^m (x - 1)^m$ and integrating by parts m times but I'm off by a factor of (m!). What are some other ways to evaluate this?

Comment: It seems the title is different from the body, shouldn't be $m\neq n$?

Comment: @Nosrati For the $ m /neq n case the integral is zero. Another form of the orthogonality condition is $(n(n + 1) - m(m+1)) /int_{-1}^{1} P_m(x) P_n(x) dx = 0$

Comment: How did you end up with that $I$? What you should have is: $$I = \frac{(-1)^m(2m)!}{2^{2m}(m!)^2}\int_{-1}^1(x^2-1)^m\;dx$$

Comment: @bames You're right. I fixed it.

Comment: @JHT It is not quite fixed yet. The denominator should have $(m!)^2$, not $(2m!)^2$ as you currently have it.

Comment: @bames Fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be solved using substitution:
\begin{align}
I &= \frac{(-1)^m(2m)!}{2^{2m}(m!)^2}\int_{-1}^1(x^2-1)^m\;dx \\
&= \frac{(2m)!}{2^{2m}(m!)^2}\int_{-1}^1(1-x^2)^m\;dx \\
&= \frac{(2m)!}{2^{2m}(m!)^2}\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}(1-\sin^2\theta)^m\cos\theta\;d\theta \\
&= \frac{(2m)!}{2^{2m}(m!)^2}\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\cos^{2m+1}\theta\;d\theta
\end{align}
Now, notice that
\begin{align}
\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\cos^{2m+1}\theta\;d\theta &= \left. \cos^{2m}\theta\sin\theta\right|_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} + 2m\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\cos^{2m-1}\theta\sin^2\theta\;d\theta \\
&= 2m\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}(\cos^{2m-1}\theta - \cos^{2m+1}\theta)\;d\theta
\end{align}
This yields the recurrence relation
$$\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\cos^{2m+1}\theta\;d\theta = \frac{2m}{2m+1}\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\cos^{2m-1}\theta\;d\theta$$
From here it is not hard to show that
$$\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\cos^{2m+1}\theta\;d\theta = \frac{2^{2m+1}(m!)^2}{(2m+1)!}$$
Therefore, we have
$$I = \frac{(2m)!}{2^{2m}(m!)^2}\frac{2^{2m+1}(m!)^2}{(2m+1)!} = \frac{2}{2m+1}$$

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will be of help. First given the even nature of the integrand

\begin{align}
I &=  \frac{(-1)^m(2m)!}{2^{2m}(m!)^2}\int_{-1}^{1} \left(x^2 - 1\right)^m \:dx= 2 \cdot  \frac{(-1)^m(2m)!}{2^{2m}(m!)^2}\int_{0}^{1} \left(x^2 - 1\right)^m \:dx\\
&=\frac{(2m)!}{2^{2m}(m!)^2} \int_{0}^{1}\left(1 - x^2\right)^m \:dx
\end{align}

Here let $t = x^2$ to yield:

\begin{align}
I &  \frac{(2m)!}{2^{2m}(m!)^2}\int_{0}^{1} \left(1 - t\right)^m \frac{\:dt}{2\sqrt{t}} =\frac{(2m)!}{2^{2m+1}(m!)^2}\int_{0}^{1}t^{-\frac{1}{2}} \left(1 - t\right)^m\:dt \\
&=\frac{(2m)!}{2^{2m+1}(m!)^2} B\left(\frac{1}{2}, m+1\right)
\end{align}

Where $B(..)$ is the [Beta Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function). Using the [relationship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Relationship_between_gamma_function_and_beta_function) between the Beta Function and [Gamma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) Function, we see that:

\begin{align}
I &= \frac{(2m)!}{2^{2m+1}(m!)^2}B\left(\frac{1}{2}, m+1\right) =  \frac{(2m)!}{2^{2m+1}(m!)^2} \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(m+1\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2} + m +1 \right)} \\
&=   \frac{(2m)!}{2^{2m+1}(m!)^2}\frac{\sqrt{\pi}m!}{ \frac{(2(m + 1))!\sqrt{\pi}}{2^{2(m + 1)} (m + 1)!}}= \frac{2}{2m + 1}
\end{align}

Comment: OP unfortunately still has a typo in his/her definition of $I$ (see my comment on their question above), which you used in your answer. It is known that $I = \frac{2}{2m+1}$.

Comment: Cheers, it certainly didn't seem right @bames - I thought to push it through to assist where required. I have made the adjustments as per your clarification. Thanks for your post.